# Visual Studio 2013 - Outlining corruption in javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, corruption, outlining

I have an environment issue using Visual Studio 2013.

The outlining feature for javascript documents will often corrupt itself after a while using it. It will remain that way until I close the solution and then delete the .suo and .sdf files from the solution up until the next corruption.

The corruption as I call it begins with something benign such as not aligning the caret position with the indent of other functions in the current scope. It will be positioned at the first character on the next line. It occurs everyday.

Then after a little while (5 mins), when you select a word, the feature that highlights the same words in the document becomes corrupt and will highlight almost random characters in different words and on multiple lines sometimes.

After a minute or less, the functions / block outlining then becomes corrupt too. Usually begins by opening all the functions/blocks bellow the current caret position. Trying to press the little '-' to minimize a code block results in visual studio not understanding what is a function anymore and outline the rest of the page.

I have no extension installed other than the default microsoft ones. I tried resetting all my settings and deleting the suo/sdf files repeatedly.

Any idea what I should try next?
Thanks.

Comment: You should try to clear VS options files, and to install Web Essentials in Visual Studio, to have an environment javascript-friendlier

Comment: I tried clearing the options from Import/Export settings Reset option. It works for a while until it happens again. I shall try Web Essentials

Comment: I found that using the /ResetUserData argument on devenv.exe in command prompt resets nearly everything and even goes through initial setup again.

So far so good, no corruption so far (hours)

Comment: if this was in fact the right approach, consider answring your own question

Comment: Indeed, still hasn't corrupted as of today. It sure did help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Unfortunately the solution I found only worked for 2 weeks or so. Back to a corrupted solution where I need once a day to delete the .suo and .sdf files.

> I found that using the /ResetUserData argument on devenv.exe in
>   command prompt resets nearly everything and even goes through initial
>   setup again. So far so good, no corruption so far (since yesterday).